# Backbone Multiple Collection Fetch and Rendering

Tags: backbone.js

I am developing a Backbone application.

I have a view named as **"Dashboard"**. In this dashboard View, I will be fetching two collections of data; one for the List of recent articles from the articles table and the other for the list of Authors from the authors table.

Please note that I have two different tables in mySQL Database, I use SlimPHP Api to make queries and retrieve data.

I am also using Handlebars templating Javascript library to compile the HTML.

**Question:**
My Question is that what is the best approach to make the two queries and then send both collections data to the Handlebars compile which will create the HTML (after looping through collection models) and eventually be taken into render function.

Here is what I have tried so far (Dashboard View Javascript File):

http://jsfiddle.net/n6c3q16r/2/

I tried to fetch two models data and pass it into the render function on line # 17 on jsFiddle:

```
this.$el.html(this.template(this.collection, this.topAuthorsCollection));
```

But this does not work.

Comment: If you have two collections, you'll either need to pass in another reference to the second collection or you'll need to build two separate views, each of which is responsible for a different collection. I'd recommend the latter unless the way you need to display the data is inextricably linked together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use promises. My personal favourite in such a scenario is `jQuery.when`

```
$.when(collection1.fetch(),collection2.fetch()).done(function(){
         //Do stuff here
});
```

API - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/n6c3q16r/4/

Comment: It gives an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: fetchOne is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.topAuthorsCollection, 'reset', this.render);
    this.topAuthors = new topAuthorsModel();
    this.topAuthorsCollection = new topAuthorsCollection({model: this.topAuthors});
    this.collection.fetch({
        reset: true,
        success: function() {
            this.topAuthorsCollection.fetch({reset: true})
        }
    });

}
```